# ActionScript Video resizing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, actionscript

I am using Actionscript 3 in Flash professional. I have a video object on stage. I would like the user be able to adjust the size of the video object at their choice. For example, when the mouse cursor hovers over the video object you can drag the video object out to either increase, decrease the width and height of the video object. 
Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this. This is my code so far. If you can give me any advice that be great!

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
cam.setMode(350, 150, 15);
cam.setQuality(0, 85);

cam.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, statusHandler);

var vid:Video = new Video();
vid.width = cam.width;
vid.height = cam.height;
vid.x = 52;
vid.y = 33;

vid.attachCamera(cam);
addChild(vid);

var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone();
mic.framesPerPacket = 1;
mic.setSilenceLevel(0, 2000);
mic.gain = 50;
mic.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;

mic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, micStatus);

var vidStream:Video = new Video();
vidStream.width = cam.width;
vidStream.height = cam.height;
vidStream.x =x=(vid.x+ cam.width +10); vidStream.y=vid.y;
addChild(vidStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, use a MOUSE_DOWN MouseEvent to trigger a listener function that uses a MOUSE_MOVE MouseEvent to change the video's size. The MOUSE_MOVE's listener function will set vid.width = vid.width + something. Or it could be - something or * something. It will do this coninually while the mouse is moving so don't forget to remove the MOUSE_MOVE listener with another function that listens for MOUSE_UP.

What that 'something' is depends on the way in which you want the size to change. But it could simply be the distance that the mouse moves from the MOUSE_DOWN point.

I could write code for you but that would take away all of the fun and the chance to learn some programming. But I'll tell you that the Video, when it's on stage, will have  'localX' and 'localY' properties that you can use to tell your program where the mouse IS in relation to the video. You can (and should) also use stageX and stageY for some of your parameters because, if your video shrinks so much that the mouse is no longer over it, the 'local' values won't work anymore,